# Templating with Twig - permanent access to a variable in all my templates

Tags: php, template-engine, twig

I've just started looking into [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org) and I'm wondering how I would accomplish the following.

I have a variable $logged_in that I need to have access to in every single page on my site, I was hoping that rather than passing this to the twig renderer every single time in the data array, there would be a way for me to declare this somewhere, and for every template to have access to it.

Do I need to build an extension to accomplish this / or is it even possible? I have looked through every page of the documentation but I'm having trouble having tried to extend the base template as described here...

[<s>Twig Documentation | Recipes | Making the Templates aware of the Context</s>](http://www.twig-project.org/book/06-Recipes) **Dead link**

Is this the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: I managed to work around this by making my application add the data to the $data array automatically before passing through to twig. I would still be interested to know if there is a way of providing these variables to twig natively without having to pass them

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just [read](http://blog.twig.sensiolabs.org/post/2665679442/twig-1-0-0-rc1-released) about the new features in the 1.0RC release which should help.

Taken from the blogpost:

**Globals:**

PHP

```
// a global can be a constant
$twig->addGlobal('pi', 3.14);

// or any other valid PHP expression, like an object
$twig->addGlobal('request', new Request());
```

Template

```
{{ pi }}

{{ request.params('name') }}
```

Comment: that will do for me :-) Thanks for the heads up.